# ArcGIS automatically convert string variables to numeric?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, table, string

If arcgis is automatically coverting string values to numeric variables in a text document generated by stata, how do you change those variables back into string? I tried opening up the fields under properties in arccatalog and it says I cannot change them because the tables are not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS reads the first 8 (maybe 11?) rows of data to determine what the data type should be for each field. Kind of a hackish workaround, but you could make some dummy rows for that and populate it with alphabetic characters. Then delete the rows once imported. Another method would be to add a new text field, and use Field Calculator to cast the values from the problem column back to text.

I'm thinking there's a better way, but my brain isn't retrieving it right now, sorry.

Comment: That seems to work, except now I'm having issues deleting the rows once imported. How do you do that?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, for my purposes that wasn't necessary. Thank you!